# Unable to get the ID of opened .docx file in Docs Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, docx

I am stuck at getting the ID of the .docx file inside Google Docs Add-on.
The Id is present in the URL of the browser but I am unable to find any method to get the browser URL.

The method `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()` is not helping because it works on Google Docs file, and the file that I open in Google doc is Microsoft Word Format (.docx) file.

I am attaching a screenshot for reference: [Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DF2O.png)

Is there any way to get the ID of .docx file inside Google Docs Add-on?
Or is there any way to get the URL of the browser when the .docx is opened in the Google Docs Add-on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

There's no way to retrieve this information for non-Google Docs in Workspace add-ons.

#### Explanation:

As you mentioned, [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app) methods only work for Google Docs files.

Also, the Workspace add-on's [Docs event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#docs_event_object) is only populated if the current document is a Google Docs. I just checked that's the case.

Finally, this information is not retrievable in the context of Workspace add-ons.

#### Feature request:

You could consider filing a feature request using [this Issue Tracker template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206) if you think this functionality could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the event object for `Workspace Addons` using this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#docs_event_object). When you build your card, you have access to the event. So you should be able to access it using `docs.id` within your function.

Comment: `{ clientPlatform: 'web',
  docs: {},
  commonEventObject: { platform: 'WEB', hostApp: 'DOCS' },
  hostApp: 'docs' 
}`

I am getting this in the event object. i am getting undefined in `docs.id or e.docs.id`. @Neven